# Chrome PWA on Android opening PDFs while offline

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've come across a specific issue that seems to have started happening in the very recent versions of Chrome, I can't specify the exact version when this started happening but I will try to fully explain the scenario.

I have a PWA application that is normally run in a chromeless window on an Android 7 tablet. When it is offline and all the applications files are cached (verified in devtools) it will not download cached PDFs. However, if I run the application in normal Chrome, still offline, the PDFs will download correctly.

The error (shown as a toast message) is simply "Cannot display PDF (xxx.pdf cannot be opened)" No errors show in the console. I added a console.log message to note when these PDF files are being served and it is only shown when not in chromeless mode.

```
if (requestUrl.pathname.startsWith('/Content/maps/') || requestUrl.pathname.startsWith('/Content/pictures/')) {
    console.log("Serving pdf or image file");
    event.respondWith(servePDF(event.request));
    return;
}
```

To me, this indicates that something is different while running PWAs in chromeless mode and I cannot find a work around or fix for this issue.

Comment: were you ever able to show a PDF on android in a PWA site?

Comment: no, I had to convert all PDFs to JPGs. However, I'm not sure if this issue has been resolved with recent updates.